# How to find volume of 3D cross-section of a 4D cube with calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> What is the volume of the 3D-object formed by the intersection between the hyperplane $x+y+z+w=2$ and a 4D cube with verticies that have coordinates 0 or 1?

By computing all the pairwise distances between the points on the plane and the cube (there are 6 points) we can quickly find that the desired 3D object is an octahedron, with a volume of $\frac 43.$

I was wondering what would the multivariable calculus method be to determine this volume? I was thinking of defining $w = 2 - x - y - z$ and evaluating something such as $$2\iiint_{0\leq x,y,z\leq1 \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\, 1 \leq x+y+z\leq 2} dA$$ but I was unsure about how to compute the actual bounds to this integral or if this integral is even correct. Is there a better way on how to set this integral up, or is there a trick to computing the above integral?

Comment: called octahedron

Comment: The better way, which may also be thought of as a trick, is to notice the symmetry of the problem and to do what you did in the first place: say "_hey, that's an octahedron, I know its volume!_"

Comment: Personally, I won't compute the volume using iterated integral. The limits are very complicated to write down and hard to generalize. Instead, I will compute the 3d-volume of regions of the form $$
V_{abcd}(t) = \verb/volume/\{ (x,y,z,w) : x \ge a, y \ge b, z \ge c, w \ge d, x + y + z + w = t \}
$$ 
and then deduce the desired volume using inclusion exclusion principle.
$$V = \sum_{a=0}^1 \sum_{b=0}^1 \sum_{c=0}^1\sum_{d=0}^1 (-1)^{a+b+c+d} V_{abcd}(2)$$